Issue with deserializing JSON into Trie structure in Unity using Newtonsoft.Json
I have a 18MB JSON file called JsonFileAsset that is a nested dictionary representation of a Trie structure with the following characteristics:
- "@" represents the end of a string.
- "#" represents children nodes in the Trie.
- "$" represents 'true', indicating the end of a word.
- "%" represents 'false', indicating not the end of a word."

where the JSON file looks like this:
{"@":"%","#":{"a":{"@":"%","#":{"a":{"@":"%","#":{"h":{"@":"$","#":{"e":{"@":"%","#":{"d": ...

Here is the code that I tried to make the deserialization process work on TrieHandler:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class TrieHandler
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> trieDict;

    public void LoadTrieFromJson(string jsonContent)
    {
        trieDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonContent);
        if (trieDict == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to parse JSON content: " + jsonContent);
        }
        Debug.Log("TrieDict size: " + trieDict.Count);
    }


    public bool IsWordValid(string word)
    {
        return IsWordInTrie(trieDict, word, 0);
    }

    private bool IsWordInTrie(Dictionary<string, object> node, string word, int index)
    {
        if (index == word.Length)
        {
            // Check if the current node represents the end of a word
            return node.ContainsKey("@");
        }

        char currentChar = word[index];

        if (!node.ContainsKey("#"))
            return false; // No children, word does not exist

        Dictionary<string, object> childrenDict = (Dictionary<string, object>)node["#"];

        if (!childrenDict.ContainsKey(currentChar.ToString()))
            return false; // Current character is not present in children

        return IsWordInTrie(childrenDict[currentChar.ToString()] as Dictionary<string, object>, word, index + 1);
    }
}

public class GameplayController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string selectedTileLetters = "";

    // Trie handler instance
    private TrieHandler trieHandler;
    private string jsonContent;

    void Start()
    {
        trieHandler = new TrieHandler();
        TextAsset jsonFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("JsonFileAsset");
        if (jsonFile != null)
        {
            trieHandler.LoadTrieFromJson(jsonFile.text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to load JSON file");
        }
    }
    ... // Rest of the code not shown
}

I tried to use Unity's native Json utility tool to get the Json asset stored at the resource directory with  trieDict = JsonUtility.FromJson<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonContent), but the trieDict.Count throws me a 0 at Console. If I tried to use the Newtonsoft.Json's JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method then I get a trieDict.Count of 2. However neither of it seem to work as expected because my JsonFileAsset file has 400k+ of key-value pair and the trieDict.Count should've printed a larger number. In other parts of the program, the IsWordValid method never returned a True boolean and I have already tested my Trie traversal algorithm and it worked perfectly fine so the problem was isolated to only the LoadTrieFromJson's faulty deserialization process.
What should I do to fix the deserialization process of LoadTrieFromJson with Newtonsoft.Json?

What makes you think Dictionary<string, object> is a correct mapping for that JSON structure?

In general when you have object in your deserialization target, you're leaving it up to the JSON implementation to try to figure out what's going on. What you get from NewtonSoft's implementation is a JObject or similar. While you could potentially navigate this to build your actual Trie structure, it's a bit of work.
If I've understood your structure correctly, and how it's represented in the JSON file, you should be able to read the file with something like this (using System.Text.Json):
class SerializedTrieNode
{
    [JsonPropertyName("@")]
    public char EOS { get; set; } = '%';
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsEndOfString => EOS == '$';
    
    [JsonPropertyName("#")]
    public Dictionary<char, SerializedTrieNode>? Children { get; set; }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int NodeCount => (Children?.Values.Sum(node => node.NodeCount) ?? 0) + 1;
    
    public bool Contains(ReadOnlySpan<char> chars)
    {
        if (chars.Length == 0)
            return IsEndOfString;
        if (Children is null || !Children.TryGetValue(chars[0], out var next))
            return false;
        return next.Contains(chars[1..]);
    }
}


I've thrown a recursive Contains method in there to give you an idea of how you can use this to search for a valid word, but no guarantees as to the speed and it's case sensitive.
Anyway, let's create a sample and see what it looks like.
First, the JSON data initialized with the word set "on", "one" and "once":
{"@":"%","#":{"o":{"@":"%","#":{"n":{"@":"$","#":{"e":{"@":"$"},"c":{"@":"%","#":{"e":{"@":"$"}}}}}}}}}

Now a couple of tests:
SerializedTrieNode rootNode = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SerializedTrieNode>(File.ReadAllText("sample.json"));

// Words we added
Console.WriteLine(rootNode.Contains("on"));     // true
Console.WriteLine(rootNode.Contains("one"));    // true
Console.WriteLine(rootNode.Contains("once"));   // true

// Partials should not match
Console.WriteLine(rootNode.Contains("o"));      // false
Console.WriteLine(rootNode.Contains("onc"));    // false

// Extras should not match
Console.WriteLine(rootNode.Contains("onto"));   // false

// Case matters
Console.WriteLine(rootNode.Contains("Once"));   // false

And of course this should serialize correctly. And it's a simple enough task to write an Add method if you want to rebuild your JSON file.

I tried integrating your solution to my code, yet Visual Studio compiler warned to remove the unnecessary using System.Text.Json; namespace. Did you use any other namespaces or references in your code that I may be missing?

@swiftenjoyer I used things from System.Collections.Generic, System.Text.Json and System.Text.Json.Serialization. Some of those namespaces are probably automatically included depending on the configuration of the project. If the compiler is telling you to remove it then it's probably safe to remove.

@swiftenjoyer Oh, and I didn't mean for you to necessarily add using System.Text.Json; to your code. I was just pointing out that this was coded against the new Microsoft Json serializer instead of NewtonSoft.Json.
